# Añadir boton de reseteo en un input

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

Este es el componente que estoy armando, quiero añadir un botón que pueda eliminar el valor solo de este input pero no encuentro la manera, probé manejarlo con estados pero no funcionó.

```html
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Input.css";

function Input(props) {
  const { placeholder, type, name, readOnly, disabled, value } = props;

  const resetInput = (e) => {

  };
  return (
    <div className="InputContainer">
      <input
        placeholder={placeholder}
        type={type}
        name={name}
        id={name}
        disabled={disabled}
        autoComplete="off"
        defaultValue={value}
      />
      <button onClick={resetInput}>Delete</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Input;
```

Comment: con `<input type="reset">` podes resetear el `form`.

Comment: Me refiero a poder eliminar solo ese campo,

Comment: lo que podrías hacer es añadir un `id` al `input` y luego con una `función` le indicas que cambie el contenido de dicho input a algo vacío `setInputValue("");`

Comment: Lo que pasa es que estoy usando React  y la manera en que se maneja el DOM es distinto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podrias usar useRef para apuntar al elemento deseado

```
import React, { useRef } from "react"

export default function TextInputWithTextButton() {
  const inputName = useRef('')
  const inputLastName = useRef('')
  const onButtonClick = (input) => {
    // `current` apunta al elemento de entrada de texto montado
    input.current.value=''
    console.log(input.current.value)
  };
  return ( 
    <>
      <div>
      <input ref={inputName} type="text" />
      <button onClick={()=>onButtonClick(inputName)}>Focus the input</button>
      </div>
      <div>
      <input ref={inputLastName} type="text" />
      <button onClick={()=>onButtonClick(inputLastName)}>Focus the input</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

En este caso la variable `value` es la valor de propiedad ingresada, por lo que la modificacion se puede realizar mediante una variable de estado definida con `useState()`:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Input.css";

function Input(props) {
  const { placeholder, type, name, readOnly, disabled, value } = props;
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(value);
  const resetInput = (e) => {
      setInputValue(''); // o setInputValue(value) para resetearlo al original
  };
  return (
    <div className="InputContainer">
      <input
        placeholder={placeholder}
        type={type}
        name={name}
        id={name}
        disabled={disabled}
        autoComplete="off"
        defaultValue={value}
      />
      <button onClick={resetInput}>Delete</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Input;
```

Referencia: https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: Ya lo intenté pero no funciona

Comment: Edite la respuesta, me di cuenta que debe usarse una variable modificable y `value` es parte de las propiedades de entrada.